# How to get igraph to use variables as vertices?

Tags: r, igraph

I feel like this is a very stupid question, but here we are.

I'm using igraph for the first time for a network analysis, and the resulting graph has values as vertices instead of the variable names... what is happening?

Thank you.

```
data <- read.spss("data.sav", use.value.labels = TRUE, to.data.frame=TRUE, add.undeclared.levels = c("no"))

g <- graph_from_data_frame(data, directed = FALSE) 

plot.igraph(g)
```

Comment: It's unclear what you mean. Please show a complete minimal example.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You'd like the plot to print some feature of the vertices rather than arbitrary numbers. You can specify a `vertex.label` as shown below.

```
plot.igraph(g, vertex.label =  get.vertex.attribute(g, "variable"))
```

Here "variable" is the name of an attribute you would like to print on each vertex.

You can learn more about plotting in the help here: `?igraph.plotting` (there's a link to this help page buried in `?plot.igraph`)